# UDP sendto never fails

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, network-programming

My application sends UDP packets to different hosts continuously. When a host is alive, UDP packet reaches to the host and `sendto` function returns number of bytes sent to it. But when a host gets down (cable unplug or reset), `sendto` function doesn't send UDP packet but still returns number of bytes in buffer. Instead of sending UDP packets, ARP packets get sent to find the host. Why `sendto` function doesn't return SOCKET_ERROR? `WSAGetLastError` function returns 0 also. How can I notice error on sending UDP packets to unreachable host?

P.S. my OS is Winodws 7 x64 and my application is native C++ and 64-bit.

Comment: what are the failure cases you've tried? just unplug cable?

Comment: By the time the error is discovered, it's way too late to return anything.

Answer (score 8):

The title of your question - "UDP sendto never fails" - is a pretty good one-line summary of UDP.

That's how UDP works - UDP doesn't care if the destination is reachable.
UDP `sendto` "succeeds" when the packet leaves your application; it doesn't even need to leave your computer as far as UDP is concerned.

The ARP packages are your computer's attempts to find a way to reach the host, but at that point `sendto` has already "succeeded".

If you want a reliable protocol, UDP is not what you're looking for.

Comment: You are right but is there any way to find out that my packet did not leave the computer and my OS is trying to find the host by sending ARP packets?

Comment: @MustafaChelik I doubt that there is, but there may be something Windows-specific you could use instead of sockets. Using a protocol that suits your purpose, or implementing one on top of UDP, could be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

A UDP `sendto()` cannot possibly return an error of that nature unless you are sending over a connected UDP socket, in which case you *may* get an error on a subsequent send.